# Client certificates for JxBrowser

Tags: jxbrowser

I am getting following exception with JxBrowser. Obviously I checked that KeyChain (I am on osx) contains correct certificates. Both Chrome and Electron are able to find it. Any advice?

> 12:58:30 SEVERE: The DialogHandler.onSelectCertificate() method has
>   thrown exception:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The
>   certificateStr cannot be null or empty.   at
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.CertificateFactory.certificatesFromString(SourceFile:27)
>     at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.g.run(SourceFile:134)    at
>   com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.q.run(SourceFile:51)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: I'm glad to let you know that the issue has been fixed. An updated EAP build with the fix is available for download from http://cloud.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/eap/jxbrowser-6.13-b10-eap-cross-desktop-win_mac_linux.zip

Please try this EAP build and let me know your feedback. The fix will be included into official 6.13 build we are planning to release this week.

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue in JxBrowser. This issue will be resolved in the next version 6.13 that we plan to release this month.

Answer (score 0):

```
Network network = engine.network();
network.set(VerifyCertificateCallback.class, (params) -> 
        VerifyCertificateCallback.Response.valid());
```

Refer link to check more about this api [jxbrowser](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/docs/guides/network.html#certificate-verification)